# Creating and uploading .CSV file dynamically using php for selenium test

Tags: php, selenium-rc

I am unable to create a .csv file in php using selenium required for executing my test case and how to upload the same.

As to run my test case i have to update and upload the .csv file so that same data is not uploaded for each execution.

Thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following PHP Code to create a csv file dynamically and give the file to the script to Upload.

`$value` is an array with the values comma seprated to be written in csv file per line.

`$output` is an array of values so that it put the values on newline.

`ran` is creaing numbers and name randomly. The file will be created in the base directory.

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $temp1=$obj->ran($fixNo);
    $temp2=$obj->ran($fixName);
    $value=array($temp1."=".$temp2,$temp1."-1",11+$i);
    $output[$i]=$value;
}
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($output as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
print_r($output);
```

Use the following to upload the file it only works in Firefox.

```
$this->type("csv_file", "C:\\file.csv");
```

For more refrence click [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)